# Batch file for MS-DOS 6.22

Tags: dos

i would like to ask about MS-DOS batch file to determine that file name in character or digits or is there a way to specify how to dir, copy or xcopy all files which it's names has numerical only.

Comment: I don't think MS-DOS comes with such a utility (it didn't support any kind of regex anywhere, as far as I know). You'd probably have to write a custom executable (`.exe` or `.com`) in the language of your choice and return the result via the exit code. There *might* be pre-made utilities for this around, but a quick search didn't turn up anything useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may find a tool appropriate in [Georg Pohl's collection](http://users.telenor.dk/~dsl645578/main/pohlutil.htm) of DOS utilities, or in the [Batfiles](http://users.telenor.dk/~dsl645578/main/download.htm) downloads.

If you do want to make a pure-batch solution, the following links from the Batfiles FAQ will get you started:
[Place first character of string into a variable](http://users.telenor.dk/~dsl645578/main/batfaq2.htm#70), [Remove 1st character of string and place remainder into variable](http://users.telenor.dk/~dsl645578/main/batfaq2.htm#72).

Answer (score -1):

there is a way to check that ...little bit messy but here you go.


for %%i in (*.*) do (

echo %%~nfile1|findstr /r "[0-9]"

if /i %errorlevel% neq 0 set result=letters

if /i %errorlevel% == 0 set result=numbers )

this should go through all files,
hide extensions, and check if all characters are numbers
if not all numbers, it will set variable %result% as letters.

hope this helps